# Drag a file from explorer and create a hyperlink into a dropped text area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, windows, explorer

i would like to drag a file from our windows file server and drop it onto a text area in webpage

the resulting link would be something like:

```
<a href="\\fileserver\folder\pizza_2.pdf">filename.pdf</a>
```

Comment: That sounds pretty cool. What have you tried so far?

Comment: this code worked if i was dragging a link from the browser to the text area but not from explorer: 'document.ondragstart = function () {
         window.event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "copyLink";
     };'

Answer (score 1):

I think following code will help you:

```
<div id="drop_zone">Drop files here</div>
<output id="list"></output>

<script>
  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();

    var files = evt.dataTransfer.files; // FileList object.

    // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
    var output = [];
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
              //** you gotta change these lines accordingly **
      //output.push('<li><strong>', f.name, '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a', ') - ',
        //        f.size, ' bytes, last modified: ',
        //        f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString(), '</li>');
    }
    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
  }

  function handleDragOver(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();
  }

  // Setup the dnd listeners.
  var dropZone = document.getElementById('drop_zone');
  dropZone.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
  dropZone.addEventListener('drop', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
```

Reference: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/#toc-selecting-files-dnd

Comment: thank you for that code Taesung. It's getting very close to what i need. i have reviewed the w3 [file API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) and could not see how to get the file location. Any more tips?

Comment: Can you access f.mozFullPath? I can see the property in debug of firebug in ff.